# How to subset a list, then truncate its elements (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have the following list, which is named `my_List`:

```
['SAMNY5PAP01_Max',
 'SAMNY5PAP02_Max',
 'SAMNY5PAP03_Max',
 'SAMNY5PAP01_Avg',
 'SAMNY5PAP02_Avg',
 'SAMNY5PAP03_Avg',
 'DVR_PUC_Max_Sum_SAMNY5PAP01',
 'DVR_PUC_Max_Sum_SAMNY5PAP02',
 'DVR_PUC_Max_Sum_SAMNY5PAP03',
 'DVR_PUC_Max_Count_SAMNY5PAP01',
 'DVR_PUC_Max_Count_SAMNY5PAP02',
 'DVR_PUC_Max_Count_SAMNY5PAP03',
 'DVR_PUC_Average_Sum_SAMNY5PAP01',
 'DVR_PUC_Average_Sum_SAMNY5PAP02',
 'DVR_PUC_Average_Sum_SAMNY5PAP03',
 'DVR_PUC_Average_Count_SAMNY5PAP01',
 'DVR_PUC_Average_Count_SAMNY5PAP02',
 'DVR_PUC_Average_Count_SAMNY5PAP03']
```

I'd like to:

a) take only the first three elements of `my_List` list (e.g.

```
['SAMNY5PAP01_Max', 'SAMNY5PAP02_Max', 'SAMNY5PAP03_Max']
```

b) then, take only the piece of the element before the `'_Max'` (e.g. `['SAMNY5PAP01', 'SAMNY5PAP01', 'SAMNY5PAP01']`

I know how to do step 'a' above, as follows:

```
my_List = my_List[0:3]
```

This returns me:

```
['SAMNY5PAP01_Max', 'SAMNY5PAP02_Max', 'SAMNY5PAP03_Max']
```

How can I accomplish step 'b' above?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about "Vanilla Python" lists or about Pandas Series/DFs?

Comment: Have you tried `split` it? `[x.split("_")[0] for x in my_list[:3]]`

Comment: Just slice the strings too: `my_list = [s[:-4] for s in my_list[:3]]`, what has this to do with `pandas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of `'_Max'` you can try this:

```
my_List = [x[:-4] for x in my_List[:3]]
```

Or this:

```
my_List = [x.split("_")[0] for x in my_List[:3]]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Carles Mitjans.

Answer (score 1):

If there are other possibilities like `_MaxLength`, etc. that would throw off indexing solutions, you can use regular expressions to accommodate those scenarios.

```
import re

[st.group(0) for st in [re.search(r'.*[^_Max]', el) for el in my_List[:3]]]
```